# How can I select !GB of data from any table? Will SAmple serve the purpose?

Tags: sql

I need to select ! GB of data from my 8GB size table. How can I achieve that?

I tried it with this SAMPLE.

```
Select * From Table_name TableSAMPLE( 0.8 PERCENT)
```

But it did not workout.

Comment: What DB engine, why 1 GB? What do want to achieve?

Comment: Are those capital `1`s in your question?

Comment: Tablesample is sql server.

Comment: If you're trying to get a subset for testing, you usually just get some number of rows.  This is especially necessary because if your table includes `VARCHAR` columns (or `TEXT` or `BLOB` or several others) there isn't a constant row length.

Answer (score 1):

What does "it did not workout" mean?  It gave you an error?  It gave you more or less data than you wanted?

If it gave you less data than you wanted, I'm not surprised.  0.8 % of 8 is 0.064, which is a lot less than 1. You'd want to select about 12.5% of the rows.  (This is assuming that where you wrote `! GB` you meant `1 GB`.)

If you're using Oracle and got an error, probably "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended", it's because you shouldn't have the word `PERCENT` following the number.  (But maybe this is valid in other systems, and I don't know which one you're using.)

You may want to use block sampling (`SAMPLE BLOCK`) instead of row sampling, I think it would be more likely to give you a proportionally-sized subset of the data.